# Get timestamp of upvote Reddit API (PRAW)

Tags: reddit, praw

Is there any way to obtain the upvote timestamp of a post e.g. bob liked post1 on the 21/12/2020 at 12:30pm?

Answer (score 2):

**No, Reddit does not provide this information**. It (generally) isn't even possible to know who upvoted a comment or submission.

In [the Reddit preferences](https://old.reddit.com/prefs/), there's an option to "make my votes public," which exposes pages at https://reddit.com/u/username/upvoted and https://reddit.com/u/username/downvoted that list submissions that the user has voted on. These listings are also available for the user who is signed in — regardless of whether the option is enabled — at https://reddit.com/u/me/upvoted and https://reddit.com/u/me/downvoted. These listings, whether accessed through the API or the web interface, do not contain a timestamp of the time the vote occurred (though as best as I can tell, they are ordered by the time that the vote was made). There is no way to access a listing of comment votes.

Here's how to access the "upvoted" and "downvoted" listings mentioned above:

```py
# for any user with the option enabled
for submission in reddit.redditor('username').upvoted(limit=None):
    print(submission.title)
for submission in reddit.redditor('username').downvoted(limit=50):
    print(submission.title)

# for the authenticated account
for submission in reddit.user.me().upvoted(limit=None):
    print(submission.title)
for submission in reddit.user.me().downvoted(limit=50):
    print(submission.title)
```

Note that for the first example you'll need to find a Reddit user who has the setting enabled. Most redditors have it disabled. Just by looking at the authors of submissions from /r/all, I was able to find that [/u/CC_Panadero](https://www.reddit.com/user/CC_Panadero) happens to have the setting enabled, if you want another account to test the first example on.